# Convert pdf file to excel using adobe reader

Tags: excel, pdf, file-conversion

I have a computer with no internet that needs to be able to convert pdf files to excel, all i have is adobe reader, getting adobe professional is impossible,

Currently i have this code, which works great for opening the pdf file using excel(or any other office application):

```
Option Explicit

Function OpenPDFPage(PDFPath As String, PageNumber As Long, PageView As Integer)

    'Opens a pdf file, at specific page and with specific view.
    'Sendkeys method is used for simulating keyboard shortcuts.
    'It can be used with both Adobe Reader & Adobe Professional.

    'By Christos Samaras

    'This line depends on the apllication you are using.
    'For Word
    'ThisDocument.FollowHyperlink PDFPath, NewWindow:=True
    'For Power Point
    'ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink PDFPath, NewWindow:=True
    'For Excel
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink PDFPath, NewWindow:=True
    SendKeys ("^+N" & PageNumber & "~^" & PageView), True

End Function

Sub Test()

    OpenPDFPage "file\path", 115, 2 'place file path here

    'Page view options:
    '0: Full Page
    '1: Zoom to 100%
    '2: Page Width

End Sub
```

How do i copy the file content to my worksheet using vba?
this is pretty much all i need, but a way to arrange the content in the pdf file to different columns would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had some time figuring it out, tried my best, if anyone have a better, more reliable code that does not rely on on key events, plz share

```
Option Explicit
Dim ShortFileName As String
Dim myRange As Range
Dim NumRows
Dim strg As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim Full_File_Path As String
Dim i As Long
Dim NumberOfPages As Long
Dim Current_Page As Long
Dim Current_Cell As Integer
Dim StartingRow As Integer
Dim WrdArray() As String
Dim text_string As String

#If VBA7 Then

    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

#Else

    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

#End If

Declare Function FindWindow _
    Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Declare Function PostMessage _
    Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal wMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    ByVal lParam As Long) As Long



Function OpenPDFPage(PDFPath As String, PageNumber As Long, PageView As Integer)


    'Opens a pdf file, at specific page and with specific view.
    'Sendkeys method is used for simulating keyboard shortcuts.
    'It can be used with both Adobe Reader & Adobe Professional.

    'By Christos Samaras

    'This line depends on the apllication you are using.
    'For Word
    'ThisDocument.FollowHyperlink PDFPath, NewWindow:=True
    'For Power Point
    'ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink PDFPath, NewWindow:=True
    'For Excel
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink PDFPath, NewWindow:=True
    SendKeys ("^+N" & PageNumber & "~^" & PageView), True


End Function
Sub Test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
     Set myRange = Range("B:B")  ' change the address to whatever suits you
     Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).InitialFileName = Range("A1").Value
     Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False

     intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
     'Select the start folder
     'make the file dialog visible to the user
     'determine what choice the user made
     If intChoice <> 0 Then
     'get the file path selected by the user
     Full_File_Path = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
     Range("A1").Value = Full_File_Path ' change the address to whatever suits you
     NumberOfPages = GetPageNum(Full_File_Path)
     ShortFileName = Dir(Full_File_Path)
     For Current_Page = 1 To NumberOfPages

    OpenPDFPage Full_File_Path, Current_Page, 1
    'Page view options:
    '0: Full Page
    '1: Zoom to 100%
    '2: Page Width
    StartingRow = 1 + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)

    For i = 1 To 11
    Debug.Print Now()
    Sleep 7
    SendKeys "^a", True
    SendKeys "^c", True
    Next i

    wb.ActiveSheet.Cells(StartingRow, 3).Value = Current_Page
    For i = 1 To 11
    Debug.Print Now()
    Sleep 7
    wb.ActiveSheet.Cells(StartingRow, 2).Select
    On Error Resume Next
    Selection.PasteSpecial
    Next i


    NumRows = 1 + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)
    wb.ActiveSheet.Cells(NumRows, 2).Value = "."



    If Current_Page = NumberOfPages Then
    Call PostMessage(FindWindow(vbNullString, ShortFileName & " - Adobe Acrobat Reader DC"), 16, 0, 0)
    End If


   For Current_Cell = StartingRow To NumRows
   text_string = Cells(Current_Cell, 2)
   WrdArray() = Split(text_string)
   For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)
   strg = strg & vbNewLine & "Part No. " & i & " - " & WrdArray(i)
   Cells(Current_Cell, 50 - i) = WrdArray(i)
   strg = 0
   text_string = 0
   Next i
   Next Current_Cell

   Next Current_Page

End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

End Sub


Function GetPageNum(PDF_File As String)
    'Haluk 19/10/2008
    Dim FileNum As Long
    Dim strRetVal As String
    Dim RegExp
    Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBscript.RegExp")
    RegExp.Global = True
    RegExp.Pattern = "/Type\s*/Page[^s]"
    FileNum = FreeFile
    Open PDF_File For Binary As #FileNum
        strRetVal = Space(LOF(FileNum))
        Get #FileNum, , strRetVal
    Close #FileNum
    GetPageNum = RegExp.Execute(strRetVal).Count
End Function
```